# Spring IoC: Calling another method than a getter

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control

Is it in Spring IoC possible to call another method than a 'common' getter?

Use-case: I need to add elements to a `java.util.Map` of a bean, but for the sake of configuration structure I do not want to do this in the same file.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: The question is not clear. You want the add element logic to write  as seperate function?

Comment: Given a bean like this:

`<bean id="A" class="java.util.Map"/>`

Is it possible to add elements to this map by referencing the bean in the configuration?

Comment: Does something like `#{A.put('key', 'value')}` work for what you want to do?

Comment: @geoand I've never heard about this. What does it exactly do? Is there any documentation about this?

Comment: It is Spring EL. You can see multiple examples at http://www.dotkam.com/2010/09/10/spring-expression-language-calling-a-method-with-parameters/ and the documentation at http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html. If that helps you, let me know so I can add it as answer for future readers of your question to easily find

Comment: @geoand Where would I put this expression in my XML configuration?

Comment: I am not sure if SpringEL would do the trick in my case:

I do have a bean "A" which contains a Map as property in the beans.xml

I do have several beans in other configuration files which's references should be passed to the Map of bean "A". I am not sure if EL is able to do this.

Comment: Wherever you need to actually populate the field

Comment: So what you need to actually have some dependencies for bean A, inside a map. Correct?

Comment: @geoand Yes; bean "A" is a registry which holds references of beans which are configured in XML files which are included in the file where bean "A" is defined.

Therefore I would like define that the references of the beans which should be held by the registry at the place where those beans are configured and not at the place where the registry is defined.

Right now I do have some text manipulation while deploying to insert the bean references in the registry definition, but this is not a nice solution for me.

Comment: @Hannes I'm afraid that I don't have any suggestions for what you are trying to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58325/discussion-between-hannes-and-geoand).